# C#: How to read text from my textfile to load into my receipt application?

Tags: c#, parsing

New here and have been using a lot of you guys knowledge, therefore thanks!

My application is almost done. The last functionality needs to be able to read text from the exported receipt and store this in the already existing context.

Link to the repo:
https://github.com/leejon1122/PracticeProjects/tree/master/GitHub/GitHub/FinanceClass2019

So when I've exported the receipt, I want to edit this with other articles or maybe other prices/amounts. I want the parse class to be able to read this text file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question lacks the specificity necessary to help you further. Without context as to what your application is written in, etc, it is difficult to provide any assistance.

Comment: What code have you written? What have you tried? What problems have you had?